# codeoutsidehtmlislocked false dreamweaver i can edit this code.?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I have to redesign a website in HTML but there is some code which is not editable in dreamviewer "codeoutsidehtmlislocked false dreamweaver" so please tell me how i can edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Notepad, Notepad++, Smultron or any simple text editor to remove that part of the code that stops you editing in Dreamweaver.

Save your changes, then it should be ok.

If you're working on remote files, you might need soemthing like Filezilla to open the files in your editor of choice.

Answer (score 2):

Open your parent template, and change the false to true. Save your template and update the child pages. Should be good to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: Open those files with Notepad and edit the concerned part.
You can also try Microsoft Expression web.